# Why does my QR code not work with the Android camera?

Tags: android, qr-code

I have made a QR code with the same URL using two different methods and one works with my Android 8.0 camera and the other does not.

**Why is this and what is the difference?**

Ideally I want to replicate what qr-code-generator.com does so my code generated QR works on the default Android camera app.

Device:
Motorola G6 (XT1925-5) Android 8.0.0
Same issue reported with user Android devices but no device details yet.

The QR code images are for reference. If you are concerned about scanning them just generate one from the websites listed yourself and try to scan it. Both QRs contain the url https://cat-bounce.com/

I have used several only QR code decoders as they all say the url contained in the QR code is the same, although the QR code looks visibly different.

**Option 1 - Works in default Android 8.0 camera.**
https://www.qr-code-generator.com/

1. Owned by bitly.
2. Works fine for iOS native camera and Google Lens.
   [image]

**Option 2 - Does not work in default Android 8.0 camera.**
https://qr-code-styling.com/

1. I use this in my app to generate the QR codes in Javascript but used the website for the attached image.
2. I tried to make it as similar as possible and used Error Correction Level M which I believe bitly uses.
3. Works fine for iOS native camera and Google Lens.
   [image]

**UPDATE:**

- Apologies if more information is needed but I am more familiar with iOS. Device information has been added.
- I have used https://zxing.org/ to analyze the codes and while the raw
  bytes are different the url contained and everything else is the
  same.

Comment: If vote down let me know why!! How can people improve questions with no feedback?

Comment: 1) Providing a QR code without the original URL data is poor form as links may lead to zero-day vulnerabilities. 2) "Default Android 8.0 camera" means nothing as OEMs can change the camera app code and you don't specify which make/model of device(s) you tested.

Comment: If you use a proper (serious) scanner app, you will find that both codes work fine. You can also analyze the codes in the software [BCTester](https://bctester.de/en/). Your issue may be with the scanner app used.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks, understood I will update the question. Although the url data is irrelevant for the question, I used the same url for both. I just used a place holder url https://cat-bounce.com/.

Comment: @MyICQ I have used several decoders online and they just show me that the content of the url is the same. The issue is not with the scanner app as it works for one of the QR codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a bug in the package that I am using.
https://github.com/kozakdenys/qr-code-styling

See the details here:
https://github.com/kozakdenys/qr-code-styling/issues/49
https://github.com/kozakdenys/qr-code-styling/pull/110

No permanent solution available yet.